# Trig and Geometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

I have this problem to solve. 
There is a triangle ABC containing a line segment bisecting Angle C with length *s*. The side opposite angle A is length *a*, across angle B is length *b* and the measure of Angle C is *2x*. How can I prove that 
s = 2ab(cos x)/(a+b)?

Answer (score 1):

Denote the intersection between bisecting line and $AB$ by $P$. Then by law of sine we know $$AP=\frac{s}{\sin{A}}\sin{x},BP=\frac{s}{\sin{B}}\sin{x}.$$
Thus $$c=AP+BP=s\sin{x}(\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}).$$
Which means
$$s=\frac{c\sin{A}\sin{B}}{\sin{x}(\sin{A}+\sin{B})}=\frac{2c\cos{x} \sin{A}\sin{B}}{\sin{2x}(\sin{A}+\sin{B})}=\frac{2c\cos{x} \cdot ab}{c\cdot(a+b)}=\frac{2ab\cos{x}}{a+b}$$